# How to track what script is causing max cpu on all 4 cores

Tags: apache-2.2

Apache noob here. I have a virtualbox instance with debian squeeze installed and apache. I'm seeing all 4 of my cores max out for about 10 minuets then it goes away. This is happening a few times per week. When I'm able to load top I can see apache processes maxed out.

/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

When I check the access log I'm not seeing a huge amount of traffic. I installed mod_evasive last week thinking they might have been a ddos or bot hammering on login pages but I can't see that in the logs. I'm suspecting there might be some bad php code somewhere. How would I go about tracing where that might be?

The web server is hosting about 4 wordpress sites for a small business and another php application with about 10 users.

I've ensured i've updated debian. I'm running on the latest wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Use mod_status to see status page. There are list of all current running requests with additinal detail, if you enable extended status.

Answer (score 0):

about to -1 for `Apache noob here` ;)

You may see something in the `access.log`. If a single php script is running for a long time, then you will see the log line when the process ends, with the time the script started.

For example:

```
<?php
  sleep(120);
  echo "hi";
```

started at 15:00 will generate a log entry at 15:02 with the timestamp 15:00.